# How do I reload/refresh components in Codename One?

Tags: java, codenameone

My data contained in such as `Label` and `Images` is dynamically updated and loaded from the `server`. How can I refresh or reload them without calling `Display.getInstance().callSerially(.)`?

If the text in my `Label` is updated, I'd like to update only that element itself. How can I do that? I can't seem to find any `refresh()` or `reload()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setText` will update the text and repaint. However, if the text size is different layout might change so you will need a `revalidate` or `animateLayout*` call to reflow the UI otherwise things might not look as you'd expect in some situations.

If you are on a separate thread (e.g. network callback that isn't on the EDT) you need a `callSerially` to avoid an EDT violation and hard to detect device bugs.

Answer (score 2):

Im not so sure, but I think can you add something like this:

```
yourlabel.repaint();
```